# Make importing a CSV string into a List of a class easier

Tags: c#, .net, linq, csv

I have 3 CSV files which I download and read into a List of a class that matches the CSV file. Now I do that using a LINQ query. Code:

```
 var ListOfCSV= CsvString.Remove(CsvString.LastIndexOf((Environment.NewLine), StringComparison.Ordinal)).Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
           .Skip(1)
           .Select(columns => columns.Split(';'))
           .Select(columns => new MyClass
           {
              argument1 = columns[0],
               argument2 = columns[1],
               argument3  = columns[2],
               argument4 = (columns[3]),
               argument5 = columns[4],
               argument6  = columns[5],
               argument7 = columns[6],
               argument8 = columns[7],
           });
```

I do that 3 times for each CSV file (as they are different classes).
Is there a way to shorten this or maybe make it faster? It is certainly not slow but I just would like to make it as fast and well performing as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checks this out, it might spare you the effort:

[FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/)

It supports reading delimited CSV files:

[Read Delimited File](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadFileDelimited/)

Comment: Thanks! Is there also a way without using an external library?

Comment: What you have done is basically what needs to be done. So, i think that's the best you can achieve.

Comment: I highly recommend FileHelpers.  It just solves so many edge-case issues that I find it just isn't worth re-inventing that wheel ever again.